# heroku data missing after upgrading database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have been following heroku docs. and after adding a new db I tried to move my data with: heroku pgbackups:transfer but I noticed that several of the recent entries are missing.. I have tried everything but unable to get those entries synced. I tried using follows and fork but it keeps saying that this feature is for production databases only!!!

I have even raised a ticket, but I doubt if I will get a response soon

Comment: Did you put your application into maintenance mode while doing the transfer?

Comment: Also, did you promote your new database so your application will use the new one going forward?

Comment: No i did not put it in maintenance but I made sure no one was using it. Now what seems like to be a new issue now is that my original database also has data missing for past few days. I have proof of that.